Email tracking - opena and clicks are being triggered without the user
I have an email client that lets you send emails and champains. I want added the ability to track open rate with a pixel and clicks with a redirect method.
The problem is that the email is being opened and sometimes all the links are being clicked and I know for sure it is not the user since they all happen in few milliseconds. Sometimes few seconds after the email has been sent and sometimes even few minutes after that.
Here is my current logic -
The pixel src is for example https://my-server.com/track/{track_id}/open/pixel.jpg
and the click redirect is https://my-server/track/{track_id}/click?target={target_url}
All the code works good and I manage to track clicks and opens but too much.
I added some user agent tracking and ip tracking and I couldn't find a user agent or specific ip range that is suspision since sometimes the same user agent and the same ip are triggered automaticaly after few seconds while also beign used few hours after (like the google image proxy)
I did notices something interesting about open rates - The Gmail app for IOS sometimes open pre-loads my pixel in the notification before the user opens the email, and then when the user does open the email it doesn't load the pixel.
I still couldn't reproduce on my end the automatic click opens but I can guess this is some security tools that scan for malewares.
Is there a way to overcome this tools? I am really lost
I can ignore open and click requests that are very close to eachother or very close to the sent time but I am afraid it will affect my rates on the other side for to much false negetive.
Thanks!
